# Как открыть терминал из среды разработки?

Tags: python

Мне нужно открыть терминал и запустить в нем несколько команд из среды разработки, а не напрямую из терминала. Вроде автоматического теста.

Не нашел ничего похожего, все предлагают стартовать скрипт наоборот из терминала.

Подскажите, как это можно реализовать?

Спасибо!

Comment: Какая среда разработки?

Comment: Python. Pycharm.